# Retrieving Files Deleted by Web Deploy

Tags: iis, .net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I just deployed an ASP.NET MVC application to IIS 7 running on Win 7 Professional. I wanted to make sure some old files got deleted with the update, so I unchecked "Leave extra files on destination (do not delete)". I protected and backed up the App_Data folder, but to my disgrace I forgot about a HUGE folder of important uploads! I just did not think it through.. On top of that the system backup had failed and is now unable to restore. Please give me some hope :/ These uploads are customer order history. They would have to be manually uploaded again one at a time if I cannot retrieve the uploads folder. They are not in the recycle bin.

```
------ Publish started: Project: ProjectName, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Transformed Web.config using Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to http://servername-pc/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE ...
Deleting filePath (Default Web Site/HTS\ ......
....
Deleting filePath (Default Web Site/HTS\Uploads\ffbca9e6-7d0b-4445-9769-cd8b2c78a1d3-Display05.jpg).
Deleting filePath (Default Web Site/HTS\Uploads\ffe0c243-e11f-4401-b80f-192affd78b57-layout.jpg).
Deleting filePath (Default Web Site/HTS\Uploads\Thumbs.db).
Deleting dirPath (Default Web Site/HTS\Uploads).
```

Comment: I have recovered some of the files w/ a free download called recuva.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any restore points available?

If so, look at the properties of the root folder if there are any previous versions available.

Comment: Thanks good idea. I ended up recovering about 90% with the recuva utility I downloaded. I was really freaking out there for a bit.